# How to export an A2C model created with stable-baselines3 to PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I have trained an A2C model (MlpPolicy) using stable-baselines3 (I am quite new to reinforcement learning and found this to be a good place to start).
However, I now want to use a XRL (eXplainable Reinforcement Learning) method to understand the model better. I decided to use DeepSHAP as it has a nice implementation and because I am familiar with SHAP.
DeepSHAP works on PyTorch, which is the underlying framework behind stable-baselines3. So my goal is to extract the underlying PyTorch model from the stable-baselines3 model. However, I am having some issues with this.

I have found the following thread: https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/issues/372
This thread did help me a bit, however, because the architecture of A2C is different from the model used in this thread, I was not yet able to solve my problem.

From what I understand stable-baselines3 offers the option to export models using

`model.policy.state_dict()`

However, I am struggling to import what I have exported through that method.

When printing out

`A2C_model.policy`

I get a glimpse of what the structure of the PyTorch model looks like. Output:

```
ActorCriticPolicy(
  (features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (pi_features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (vf_features_extractor): FlattenExtractor(
    (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  )
  (mlp_extractor): MlpExtractor(
    (policy_net): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=49, out_features=64, bias=True)
      (1): Tanh()
      (2): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=64, bias=True)
      (3): Tanh()
    )
    (value_net): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=49, out_features=64, bias=True)
      (1): Tanh()
      (2): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=64, bias=True)
      (3): Tanh()
    )
  )
  (action_net): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=5, bias=True)
  (value_net): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=1, bias=True)
)
```

I tried to recreate it myself but I am not fluent enough with PyTorch yet to get it work...

So my question is: **how can I export the stable_baselines3 model to PyTorch?**

I have tried re-building the model architecture in PyTorch according to the output of printing A2C_model.policy. My code is currently:

```
import torch as th
import torch.nn as nn

class PyTorchMlp(nn.Module):  
        def __init__(self):
                nn.Module.__init__(self)

                n_inputs = 49
                n_actions = 5
        
                self.features_extractor = nn.Flatten(start_dim = 1, end_dim = -1)
        
                self.pi_features_extractor = nn.Flatten(start_dim = 1, end_dim = -1)
        
                self.vf_features_extractor = nn.Flatten(start_dim = 1, end_dim = -1)
        
                self.mlp_extractor = nn.Sequentail(
                    self.policy_net = nn.Sequential(
                        nn.Linear(in_features = n_inputs, out_features = 64),
                        nn.Tanh(),
                        nn.Linear(in_features = 64, out_features = 64),
                        nn.Tanh()
                    ),
        
                    self.value_net = nn.Sequential(
                        nn.Linear(in_features = n_inputs, out_features = 64),
                        nn.Tanh(),
                        nn.Linear(in_features = 64, out_features = 64),
                        nn.Tanh()
                    )
                )
        
                self.action_net = nn.Linear(in_features = 64, out_features = 5)
        
                self.value_net = nn.Linear(in_features = 64, out_features = 1)
        
    
            def forward(self, x):
                pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to export it as a pytorch model for the purposes of using the DeepExplainer from the shap framework, all you need to do is create a class to wrap the models' `policy_net` and the `action_net` together. My solution was implemented stable-baselines3's PPO (MLP) model but I'm sure it wont be to different for the A2C.

My Wrapper class for my PPO (MLP) model:

```
import shap
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from stable_baselines3 import PPO

class sb3Wrapper(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(sb3Wrapper,self).__init__()
        self.extractor = model.policy.mlp_extractor
        self.policy_net = model.policy.mlp_extractor.policy_net
        self.action_net = model.policy.action_net

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.policy_net(x)
        x = self.action_net(x)
        return x
```

With regards to the shap frameworks deep explainer you are going to need to make sure of a few things

1. You need to make sure the that both the model and the state data (as a torch tensor) you are passing into the `DeepExplainer` function are on the same device (i.e. 'cuda'/'cpu')
2. If your state data is is continuous, make sure you use the `torch.FloatTensor()` function

Here is a few lines from my implementation to help you along the way:
(I extracted and stored all my data in a dataframe because I'm also performing other analyses)

```
model = PPO.load(model_path, device='cuda')
state_log = np.array(df['observation'].values.tolist())
data = torch.FloatTensor(state_log).to('cuda')
model = sb3Wrapper(model)
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, data)
shap_vals= explainer.shap_values(data)
```

References and helpful links:

- [Shap framework Github issue](https://github.com/shap/shap/issues/2384) where the person wanted to use stable_baselines3 DQN with the DeepExplainer
- [stable-baselines3 Github issue](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/508) on accessing every layer of a network

  - This might help you if you want to wrap the model layer by layer (I haven't tried that out tho)
- [Kaggle code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/subinium/shap-deep-explainer-pytorch-ver) that had useful information on using the `DeepExplainer` on pytorch models.